# Lock screen force close.when slide the phone reboots it continually persists.:-\

Tags: lock-screens

I installed a widget locker lock screen app for my android 4.1.I didn't liked it so I directly uninstalled. Now every time I try to slide on the lock the phone reboots. Again after boot when I touch the lock it reboots .what to do now. I think it is a sort of service problem .

Comment: Can you boot into [safe-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info)? If so, check there if that app did really uninstall. Though a [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) should certainly solve the issue, that would mean all your apps and data to be wiped from the device.

Comment: It is uninstalled. And i don't like to factory reset .i have rooted device